How can I version Databricks workflows while developing in dev Databricks workspace?
I am developing workflows in Databricks using workflow designer UI. I do not see any option in Databricks UI to link workflow to a repository so that we can save the workflow artifacts directly in repository's branch and then use CI/CD with repo to promote workflow to higher environment. It seems to me that workflows in Databricks are not source controlled.
Need suggestion on best practices while working on Databricks workflows, and how can we save the workflow artifacts to repository while developing in Databricks UI.
I found below DAB (Databricks Asset Bundle) from Databricks documentation
https://docs.databricks.com/en/_images/bundles-cicd.png 

Asset Bundles would indeed be a good way to do this. If you make a workflow in the UI, you can click the option "Switch to code version (YAML)" and this gives you a good start on what to put in your repository. You need to make some changes to it to make it work, but you can deploy that to multiple environments using the databricks bundle deploy command and also trigger the runs in your deployment pipelines. `

Can I also automate it or getting YAML/JSON for the workflow and making some changes to it and putting it to version control system (Git) has to be a manual activity?

Since you have to make some changes to it, I would say it is not possible. Next to that, I also wouldn't recommend it. You should have control of your version control yourself. Once you got used to the YAML definition, it shouldn't be too hard to make changes to it.
